# How to keep data secret - getting a variable from one PHP file to another

Tags: php, security, access-control

I have a PHP file, which contains a dynamic `$pointer` variable (retrieved via GET - alternatively POST if you prefer).

Embedded into the PHP file is an object/script/app (flash object *.swf) which gets loaded with HTML.

This object loads content dynamically from an XML file.

However the XML file is really just another PHP file, which with `.htaccess` and `header()` mocks an XML. This allows for the XML file to generate data dynamically. And it does generate data dynamically by using the `$pointer` variable from our original PHP file.

`$pointer` is basically an ID number for a row in a database.

This thing is: I want to keep the contents of the database secret!

My current set up will probably be secret enough for 99% of the people who will ever see this. But I do have a leak currently... If you know the location of the XML file (which can be found out by looking into the code of the object) you can load the XML file right after the PHP file has loaded, but before the object has been loaded, and you will see all the secret data revealed.

That is because currently my XML file gets the `$pointer` variable via `$_SESSION['pointer']` (that's where I stored it when we were in the PHP file). Now the XML will unset this variable after showing it once - but, like I said, if that once has been done by someone who was quick enough to access the XML before the object accessed it, all my secrets are revealed.

**What's a safer, better way to keep my secrets?**

Comment: At some point, the data is going to be transmitted in plain text and might beable to be found out at that point

Comment: what's so secret that you put it in a plaintext xml file that is served to the client?

Comment: File paths... But that should be irrelevant. it's unfortunately the only way to get the data to the object.

Comment: If the data is send to the client then it can be considered insecure and it should contain no information that you don't want that particular user to know.

If it contains file paths in URLs, then the way to go would be to secure these URLs so they cannot be accessed by anyone outside of the current session. However, there is no way to secure the contents, as it will need to be read by the client side plug-in. You could encrypt it, and add code in your client-side plug-in to decrypt, but this would be subject to decompilation so it is not, by any means, a foolproof method.